# Type of test dataset from the SVC classifier from sklearn

Tags: svm

I am trying to run an SVM script on the Kaggle dataset of Titanic.

This is the result of the .info() method of my dataset:

[info method result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqcCv.png)

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df.drop(['Survived'], axis=1)
y = df['Survived']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.33, random_state=10)

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)
clf.score(X_test,y_test)
```

This is working as intended. But if I try to cast the Survived column as int8 by doing the:

```
df = df.astype(
    {'Survived':'Int8',
     'Pclass':'Int8',
     'SibSp': 'Int8',
     'Parch': 'Int8'})
```

then I get the error shown in the image.
Why is that the case?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re18E.png)

Comment: Some of the columns have non-numeric information (like Name, Ticket, and others) which will need to be encoded as numbers before being passed to a model. Not sure if that's causing this specific error, as I haven't been able to replicate the exact error you're seeing. But it will eventually cause the model to error if not dealt with.

Comment: Those column i have removed already from the dataset. Here the problem is only the column "Survived". When casted as Int8 it will cause problem that i don't have if i leave the column as Int64

Comment: I see. I haven't been able to replicate the error. Seems to work for me when I load the dataset and convert that column: `pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')[['Survived']].astype({'Survived': 'Int8'})` gives me `Dtype: Int8` after I check it. Worth running `df.astype(...)` on one column at a time, unless you've already tried that.